# List comprehension that will return true or false given a list of numbers

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The list of numbers that I am given:

```
L= [9,29,27,11]
```

I am also given a def function:

```
is_awesome(L)
```

I need to create a one line program, that will take the numbers of the list L and return True if none of the numbers are divisible by 3 and if there is a number in the list that contains the number 1. The program will have to return False if either one of the numbers is divisible by 3 or if the list doesn't contain at least one number that has the number 1 in it.
This is what I have so far:

```
def is_awesome(L):
return [i for i in L if i % 3==0 if "3" in str(i)==True]
```

Comment: What's your question about this? Anything not working? If yes: try to write up your algorithm in more than that one line. If it is working, start to reduce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
def is_awesome(L):
    return all([i%3!=0 for i in L]) and any(['1' in str(i) for i in L])
```